# Adminhtml order grid add column

Tags: magento-1.9, database, adminhtml, order-grid

I would like to add column to the backend order grid.

I then followed this tutorial : [Tuto](https://www.atwix.com/magento/column-to-orders-grid/)

on this model, I then tried to add a second column : the client company

I tried :

```
    <?php
class Mine_Ordergridmodule_Model_Observer
{

public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(array('payment'=>$collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('payment_method'=>'method'));

        //$select->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('company_name'=>'company'));
        $select->joinLeft(array('company'=>$collection->getTable('sales_flat_order_address')), 'company.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('company_name'=>'company'));


    }

}
```

and in my layout xml :

```
<layout>
    <sales_order_grid_update_handle>
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>payment_method</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Payment Method</header>
                    <index>payment_method</index>
                    <filter_index>payment.method</filter_index>
                    <type>text</type>
                </arguments>
                <after>grand_total</after>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>company</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Company</header>
                    <index>company</index>
                    <type>text</type>
                </arguments>
                <after>shipping_name</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

but it is not working...

Comment: You can follow this Tutorial From Inchoo http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/

Comment: @Ashish @ Alexglvr : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196004/57334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution Here : [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108729/zip-code-to-order-grid-backend)

which gives :

```
<?php
class Mine_Ordergridmodule_Model_Observer
{

public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(array('payment'=>$collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('payment_method'=>'method'));

        $select->join(
                array('address' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
                'main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "billing"',
                array('company')
            );
    }

}
```

The added Helper function :

```
<?php
class Mine_Ordergridmodule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

 public function getCompanyColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header' => 'Company',
            'index' => 'company',
            'type' => 'text',               
        );
    } 
}
```

the XML

```
<layout>
    <sales_order_grid_update_handle>
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>payment_method</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Payment Method</header>
                    <index>payment_method</index>
                    <filter_index>payment.method</filter_index>
                    <type>text</type>
                </arguments>
                <after>grand_total</after>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>company</columnId>
                <arguments helper="mine_ordergridmodule/getCompanyColumnParams" />
                <after>shipping_name</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```